# How to remove content from Javascript array when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a form that lets users select checkboxes. I am able to create an array that takes the textContent of the checkbox. It works whenever they are selected, however, I would like to have the text removed from the array whenever a box is unchecked. Currently, when a box is unchecked it adds the box that is unchecked to the array. I realize that is because anytime the on change function happens (i.e. checked/unchecked) my code will populate the array. I am just looking for something that will remove the string whenever it is unchecked. Any suggestions?

html:

```
<section id="extra-features">

                    <div class="span3">
                    <label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Instagram
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Review site monitoring
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Google+
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> LinkedIn
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Pinterest
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> FourSquare
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Tumblr
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Advertising
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Javascript:

```
 var options = [];
 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
            if(this.checked){
        options.push(this.parentNode.textContent.trim());
           }
    }
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/4dFGd/

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're looking to do. You want the checkbox to be removed once it's unchecked or when it is checked? Or do you only want it removed from the array?

Comment: i want it to be removed from the array. i.e. when instagram is checked, options would be ["Instagram"]. Whenever instagram gets unchecked, I need options to be [];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Here is how I would do it with a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dFGd/2/)**

### Make `options` an object

```
var options = {};
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');

function getOptions() {
    var optionsArray = [];
    for (var key in options) {
        optionsArray.push(options[key]);
    }
    return optionsArray;
}

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onchange = function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                options[this.id] = this.parentNode.textContent.trim();
            } else {
                delete options[this.id];
            }
            console.log(getOptions());
        }
}
```

### Add an id to your checkboxes

```
<section id="extra-features">

                        <div class="span3">
                        <label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Instagram
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Review site monitoring
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Google+
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> LinkedIn
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox5" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Pinterest
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" id="Checkbox6" data-toggle="checkbox"> FourSquare
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="Checkbox6" type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Tumblr
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" id="Checkbox7" data-toggle="checkbox"> Advertising
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </section>
```

Comment: I am trying to call optionsArray in a console.log(optionsArray[1]), however it is saying that optionsArray is not defined. Can you assist me with this?

Comment: Basically, I plan on printing out optionsArray[i] into an email. I want it to show up as Instagram, Google+ as opposed to ["Instagram", "Google+"]

Comment: Oh, that's because `optionsArray` is in the function `getOptions` scope. Just assign the result of `getOptions` to a variable, then you'll be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

using your existing code, ala Array [].

http://jsfiddle.net/4dFGd/4/

```
var options = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');

    for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].onchange = function() {
                var txt = this.parentNode.textContent.trim();
                options.push(txt);
                if(this.checked === false){
                    while (options.indexOf(txt) !== -1) {
                      options.splice(options.indexOf(txt), 1);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```