# Add and remove items with the same value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm struggling with something that in theory was pretty simple but I cant' find why I can't make it work.

I need to add elements to an empty array and delete them if the values are the same. I already have a list with checkboxs that are filling the array with those values. As you can expect, I want to remove the value from the array when I uncheck the checkbox. That's it: when I check I want to add the value, when I uncheck I want to remove the same value.

I tried with `filter()`, `find()`, and even `splice()` but for some reason, I couldn't make it work.

Let me show you the code:

HTML:

```html
<div v-for='tag in tags' :key='tag.slug' class="mt-5">
  <div>
    <label class="inline-flex items-center p-2">
      <input type="checkbox" @change='selectedTags(tag.slug)'  class="form-checkbox">
         <span class="ml-2 text-custom-blue">{{ tag.name }}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedChecksArray: [],
  };
},
```

Method:

```
methods: {
  selectedTags(tag) {
    this.selectedChecksArray.push(tag)
  },
```

Of course, it just keeps adding and adding `tag` on the `selectedChecksArray` array despite I check or uncheck the checkbox because of the `push()` method.

Any advice will be appreciated. Cya!

Comment: You need to check contents of the `selectedChecksArray`, you need to edit your `selectedTags` function, it won't do what you ask for unless you make it do it.

Comment: You'll find reduced reusable code that clearly runs here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589681/how-to-remove-content-from-javascript-array-when-checkbox-is-unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `selectedChecksArray` contains the selected tag. If it contains, remove it. If not, add it.

```js
selectedTags(tag) {
  if (this.selectedChecksArray.includes(tag)) {
    this.selectedChecksArray.splice(this.selectedChecksArray.indexOf(tag), 1)
  } else {
    this.selectedChecksArray.push(tag)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks baymax, it worked like a charm. I was missing the ```includes()```. I already marked it as the correct question. Thanks again!